# Llenar Crystal Reports con Objeto/Clase C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
public class mapIngresoVista
{
   public string factura { get; set; }
   public string poliza { get; set; }
   public DateTime fecha { get; set; }
   public string via { get; set; }
   public int bruto { get; set; }
   public int neto { get; set; }
   public int bultos { get; set; }

 }
```

Ya use por ejemplo el campo "factura" para que cuando cargue el reporte me muestre el dato

En el controlador tengo el siguiente codigo que es donde "cargo el datasource" del reporte para que este muestre el dato (en este caso factura)

```
public mapIngresoVista mp = new mapIngresoVista();

public ActionResult RPVistaPreviaIngreso()
{
   ReportePrevio_Ingresos rd = new ReportePrevio_Ingresos();
   rd.SetDataSource(mp.factura);
   Stream s = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
   return File(s, "application/pdf");
}
```

> (La propiedad factura antes de entrar aca, ya esta previamente cargada
>   usando js)

Al final mi resultado es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se muestra una clase en un reporte?

**ACTUALIZACION**

Usando el breakpoint me di cuenta que factura es `null`asi que trate de darle un valor para ver si se trataba de eso pero me genera un error:

```
mp.factura = "5454";
ReportePrevio_Ingresos rd = new ReportePrevio_Ingresos();
rd.SetDataSource(mp.factura);
Stream s = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
return File(s, "application/pdf");
```

En esta linea `rd.SetDataSource(mp.factura);` me genera este error:

> 'La columna '' no pertenece a la tabla
>   IKORSYSTEM.Models.mapIngresoVista.'

Comment: Yo creo que en el setdatasource debes de pasarle un dataset o un datatable, pero un string? Para eso yo usaría mejor un parámetro.

Comment: @Juanjo Como pasaria la clase a dt o ds, esa es mi duda ahora

Comment: @Baker1562 si solo es un dato el que tienes que mostrar en este caso factura, mejor pasar el valor como parametro como aconseja juanjo

Comment: @LuisCarlosDonadoAvella de hecho son varios datos, estoy mostrando `factura` para probar si el reporte como lo estaba haciendo funcionaba, por eso aunque pase uno, despues tendre que ver como pasar la clase entero que es lo que no se como hacerlo

Comment: @Baker1562 tienes que mostrar un solo elemento de la clase o varios elementos de la clase?

Comment: @LuisCarlosDonadoAvella todos los que estan en la clase de la pregunta, actualizo la pregunta porque me surgio un error

Comment: @Baker1562 tal vez no me hice explicar, en el reporte debes mostrar todos los elementos de la clase o tienes muchos objetos de esa clase que debes mostrar?

En otras palabras debes motras un unico "mapIngresoVista" o varios "mapIngresoVista" ?

Comment: @LuisCarlosDonadoAvella estoy tomando los datos de inputs y con ajax los asigno a cada uno de los elementos de la clase, despues estoy usando el reporte para mostrar cada valor que tengan esos elementos (como un vista previa), la respuesta es si, debo mostrar todos los elementos de la clase

Comment: No contesto mi pregunta, es uno o varios "mapIngresoVista" los que debe mostrar?, si solo es uno, utilice parametros, si son varios le sugiero que los convierta a una tabla o a una lista.

Comment: @LuisCarlosDonadoAvella solo uno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución ene este caso es que en el diseño del reporte agregue 7 parametros:
factura
poliza
fecha
via
bruto
neto
bultos

El tipo de parametro de acuerdo a la definicion de la clase, luego esos parametros los inserta en el cuerpo del informe en la ubicacion que necesite.

Finalmente en el codigo elimine la parte del datasource y pase los valores de los parametros que ene est caso son los elementos de la clase:

```
ReportePrevio_Ingresos rd = new ReportePrevio_Ingresos();
rd.SetParameterValue("par1", par1);
rd.SetParameterValue("par2", par2);
.
.
.
Stream s = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
return File(s, "application/pdf");
```